# NSIS: calling DLL function with System::Call using absolute path with blanks

Tags: dll, path, nsis

I'm trying to call the function `int MyFunction()` from myfile.dll and to display it's return value in a message box.

What works so far:

```
  SetOutPath "$TEMP"
  File "myfile.dll"
  ;File "System.dll" for some time I thought one needs to copy the plugin, but that's not needed
  MessageBox MB_OK "$0"
  System::Call '$TEMP\myfile.dll::MyFunction()i.r0'
  MessageBox MB_OK "$0"
  System::Free 0
```

As soon as I replace `$TEMP` by `$INSTDIR` it doesn't work anymore. Actually it does, as long as `$INSTDIR` doesn't contain blanks, what `C:\Program Files (x86)` unfortunately does ...

At one point I figured out from [this NSIS forum post](https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-322837.html) that this behavior is a bug, namely [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/bugs/546/). I didn't really figure out what's the status of it.

I also tried the workaround with `kernel32::LoadLibrary` and `kernel32::GetProcAddress` that was presented in both pages, but I don't know what to use in the line `System::Call "::$1(the usual parameters here)"`.

So how do I call MyFunction() now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System plug-in supports quotes in the path now:

```
System::Call '"$InstDir\MyLibrary.dll"::MyFunction(i 42)'
```

Calling KERNEL32::AddDllDirectory is required if the DLL depends on other DLLs in the same directory but a single DLL should work without it.

When using kernel32::GetProcAddress the parameters are the same, it is only the path and function name that has changed to a direct address.

Comment: Found it: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixF.html#F.4.2.1
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it in the end, was adding `$INSTDIR` to the search path, as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45568677/4609258):

```
 System::Call 'KERNEL32::AddDllDirectory(w "$INSTDIR")'
```